# Adding thread objects to priority queue

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, priority-queue, python-2.6

I have a scenario where there are 3 task. A,B,C. A has no dependency. B is dependent on A. C Has no dependency. I need to run tasks A and C in parallel and then run task B once after A is complete. I am thinking priority queue with threading is the best approach. Please suggest

```py
 for task in listTasks:
    if not len(depDic [task]):
       th = threadObject()
       th.start() 
    else:
       '''trying to figure out this logic'''
```

```py
listTasks= ['A','B','C']
depDic = { 'A' :[], 'B':[A], 'C': '']
```

Comment: The easy solution is to launch only two threads, and have the first thread execute task A and then task B, while the second thread executes task C as before.

Comment: Ok I'm thinking of scenario where D is dependent on both B and C. How to handle this case? I would like to use some of priority queue if possible or some graph.

Comment: Have D's thread call `join()` on each of the other Python thread objects before executing task D.  That way D will block inside a `join()` call until the `B` and `C` threads have exited.

Comment: I have like 20 different tasks that I need to run the threads. The problem with `join()` is if I use a threadpool of size say 5, I may lose the reference to the thread that I want to join?